# Export Data from Snowflake to Salesforce CRM

Tags: salesforce, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, analytics

I need your opinions & suggestions on integration of snowflake with the salesforce CRM. I want to export table data(around 700 records) from Snowflake to CRM. Is there a way, I can directly push the data to CRM without using any 3rd party tools like Census etc. I need something which required minimum resources & automated. I already researched a lot about it. Need your inputs regarding the same as well.

Thank you

Comment: Directly I don't know, but you can always export the table from Snowflake into a CSV file and then import it in Salesforce via their native [Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to automate this by orchestrating the below steps(I assumed you are on AWS)

1. unload the snowflake table to S3
2. Use AWS APPFLOW to push the data to salesforce